# Ruby sorting multiple values

Tags: ruby

I got a little problem trying to sort the given of prices and products.

```
arr = [[6,"iPhone"],[4,"Android"],[5,"iPhone"],[3,"Xbox"],
       [9,"Android"],[8,"Xbox"]]
```

But i need to sort it by product and then by price. I make the next common to do it:

```
arr.sort_by! {|x| [x[1],x[0]]}.reverse
 => [[6, "iPhone"], [5, "iPhone"], [8, "Xbox"], [3, "Xbox"], 
     [9, "Android"], [4, "Android"]]
```

But i need again to sort it now by the block of products to get the most expensive one block first and so on. The result that I'm looking for its like:

```
arr = [[9,"Android"],[4,"Android"],[8,"Xbox"],[3,"Xbox"],
       [6,"iPhone"],[5,"iPhone"]]
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**Update 1**
I have tested Dave's answer and its works but on other set of items i didn't get the right sort of the block of products.

```
arr = [[6.0,"iPad 2"], [7, "Mints"], [6.0, "Nerf Crossbow"], [4.5, "iPad 2"],
[6, "Mints"], [6.75, "Nerf Crossbow"], [6.0, "iPad 2"], [5, " Mints"],
[9.0, "Nerf Crossbow"]]
```

I got this result:

```
1.9.2p320 :5 >   arr.sort! { |a, b| (a[1] <=> b[1]).nonzero? || b[0] <=> a[0] }  
=> [[7, "Mints"], [6, " Mints"], [5, "Mints"], [9.0, "Nerf Crossbow"], 
[6.75, "Nerf Crossbow"], [6.0, "Nerf Crossbow"], [6.0, "iPad 2"], [6.0, "iPad 2"], 
[4.5, "iPad 2"]]
```

The problem is that i was expecting

```
[[9.0, "Nerf Crossbow"], [6.75, "Nerf Crossbow"], [6.0, "Nerf Crossbow"],
[7, "Mints"], [6, "Mints"], [5, "Mints"],[6.0, "iPad 2"], [6.0, "iPad 2"],
[4.5, "iPad 2"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, just negate the price:

```
arr.sort_by! {|price, product| [product.downcase, -price]}
```

This is clearer and faster than using `sort`. I added `downcase` to the product name as you probably shouldn't care about the case.

Comment: It gives a wildly different result, however.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Oups, didn't notice I needed to reverse the order of the elements. Fixed.

Comment: +1 Far clearer what's going on here and doesn't introduce excessive logic.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option:

`arr.sort_by { |e| [e[1], -e[0]] }`